# Can Scalas manifest.erasure be correctly typed?

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I have a Java class that takes a generic type parameter and a class object related to that type:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public Foo(Class<? extends T> type) {
    ...
    }
}
```

At first I thought I could make a clever wrapper for this in Scala:

```
class Bar[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
    ...
    new Foo[T](m.erasure)
    ...
}
```

But this results in a compiler error similiar to this:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : java.lang.Class[_$1(in value <local Bar>)] where type _$1(in value <local Bar>)
required: java.lang.Class[_ <: T] 
class Bar[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) { new Foo[T](m.erasure) }
```

I think I understand why this happens, but is there any way I could get the correct type of class and make this code compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `m.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]`?

By the way, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920820/creating-a-classt-from-a-manifestt-without-casting) for an explanation of why `erasure` returns `Class[_]` and not `Class[T]`.

Comment: As always, the answer was too simple. Thanks.