# Creating a Class[T] from a Manifest[T] without casting

Tags: scala, type-erasure, raw-types

Given an `ev: Manifest[T]` I can get a `Class[T]` using `ev.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]`. It's a shame that `ev.erasure` alone returns a static type of `Class[_]`.

Can I get a `Class[T]` from a manifest without casting? If not is there a reason why the blessed Scala creators have gone for a raw return type in the `erasure` method?

I understand this may have a negligible impact on most code but I've run into this issue in an arguably non-idiomatic piece of Scala code and am curious more than anything else.

Comment: You probably mean `ev.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]`, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to do the cast yourself — and it should be so. This cast is potentially unsafe, depending on what you want to do with the returned `Class` instance. Imagine I want to roll in my own version of a cast:

```
def cast[T](obj: Any)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) =
  m.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]].cast(obj)
```

This is dangerous — as indicated by the unchecked `asInstanceOf`. Why? Because this code runs fine with such nonsense, for instance:

```
val listInt = List(1, 2, 3)
val listString = cast[List[String]](listInt)
```

There, a `List[Int]` typed as a `List[String]`. And this compiles and runs fine, but you'll probably get a `ClassCastException` later in your code at an unexpected line. That's why you cannot directly get a `Class[T]` from a `Manifest[T]` — because it is unsafe.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for returning the erased type is that `Manifest` is almost always used in generic code where you don't *actually* have the type in hand.  This forces you to explicitly declare your intentions instead of mistakenly assuming that it actually checks that the type is the one you want.

You can of course use the enrich my library pattern to add your own method that preserves types:

```
class ClassFriendlyManifester[T](m: Manifest[T]) {
  def toClass = m.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}
implicit def manifests_like_classes[T](m: Manifest[T]) = new ClassFriendlyManifester(m)

def example[T: Manifest] = implicitly[Manifest[T]].toClass

scala> example[String]
res2: Class[String] = class java.lang.String

def example2[T](implicit ev: Manifest[T]) = ev.toClass

scala> example2[String]
res5: Class[String] = class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala's typesystem isn't expressive enough to give the correct type for `erasure`. The correct type would be similar to the one for [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where |X| is the
>   erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is
>   called.

In this case, I think the correct type would be `Class[|X|]` (because `Manifest[T]` is invariant in its type parameter).  This is different to `Object.getClass()`, because in that case the static type and runtime type could be different:

```
Number n = 0; 
Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
```

Here, the runtime type of `c` would be `Class<Integer>`, not `Class<Number>`.

Comment: So the heart of the problem is that scala type system cannot express erasure and `Class<? extends X>` wouldn't be good enough?